# I'm getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one of file or text needs to be provided to readJSON, when trying to capture custom payload

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, dynatrace

I have have writing the below script, to integrate monitoring tool with jenkins, but get a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: At least one of file or text needs to be provided to readJSON, when trying to capture custom payload.

```
`stage('Extract value from Dynatrace custom payload') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def payload = sh (
                        script: 'echo $GENERIC_PAYLOAD', 
                        returnStdout: true
                    )
                    def json = readJSON text: payload
                    def problemTitle = json.problemTitle
                    println "Problem Title: ${problemTitle}"
                }
            }
        }
      stage('ReceiveWebhook') {
         steps {
            genericWebhook(
               webhookUrl: 'https:myjenkinsendpoint.com',
               requestBody: true,
           `your text`    contentType: 'JSON',
               triggerOnHeader: false,
               useCrumbIssuer: false,
               printContributedVariables: true
            )
         }
      }
          stage('Receive Webhook') {
             steps {
                script {
                   def response = httpRequest customHeaders: [[name: 'Content-Type', value: 'application/json']], url: '<webhook_url>'
                   def payload = readJSON text: response.getContent()
                   echo "Problem Notification: ${payload.problemTitle}"
                   echo "Problem Details: ${payload.problemDetails}"
                }
             }
          }`
```

I just tried tested the but got this error`your text`

Comment: So simply you are not getting a response.